# How can I write a command chain (including long queries/fetches) effectively?

Tags: command-line, bash

I often need to write command chains like:

```sh
curl api.example.com | jq '.files[].url' | xarg curl | grep 'Tel:\d+' > output
```

But it takes a lot of trial and error:

```sh
curl api.example.com | jq '.file[]' # error
curl api.example.com | jq '.files[].url' # ok, continue
curl api.example.com | jq '.files[].url' | xarg curl | grep '\d+' # error
curl api.example.com | jq '.files[].url' | xarg curl | grep 'Tel:\d+' > output # ok
```

Writing part of it and running it every time **will cause multiple HTTP requests.**

Is there any way/tool that will help me write chains effectively and efficiently? For example something that will cache the result of the chain until it's changed, an incremental `memoize` of some sort.

My current solution is to pipe each `curl` to a file so I can run parsing from that, but it take a lot of manual work:

```sh
curl api.example.com | jq '.file[]' # error
curl api.example.com | jq '.files[].url' # ok
curl api.example.com | jq '.files[].url' | xarg curl > temp
cat temp | grep '\d+' # error
cat temp | grep 'Tel:\d+' # ok
# It works! Now, compose the final chain again:
curl api.example.com | jq '.files[].url' | xarg curl | grep 'Tel:\d+' > output
```

Answer (score 0):

That would be really handy but I don't know that such a thing exists. If your script can handle some boilerplate I might try something like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

set -eo pipefail

TIMEOUT=1
CACHE_FILE=/tmp/cache.tmp

req () {
    URL="$1"
    ARGS="${*:2}"
    if find "$CACHE_FILE" -mmin -${TIMEOUT} 2>/dev/null | grep . > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        echo "Using cache file" >&2
        cat "$CACHE_FILE"
    else
        echo "Making new request" >&2
        curl -s $ARGS "$URL" | tee "$CACHE_FILE"
    fi
}


req "https://base-template.squarespace.com/blog/?format=json-pretty" | jq ".website.id"
```

Depending on how flexible it needs to be you might need to adjust the cache file name to be unique per URL, or move the timeout to arguments. Happy to help with modifications if you'd like.